# In GTA 5 story mode, my health is not regenerating

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I don't know why but my health is not regenerating when I lose damage in GTA 5 story mode. I have tried turning my game off and restarting and everything even cleaning the disk, but it is not working.

Comment: do you mean your health isnt regenerating? or you aren't increasing your max health?

Comment: No it is not regenerating

Comment: I haven't played GTAV very extensively, but I don't think it *does* regenerate. If someone who does know the game better can chime in that'd be great.

Comment: It only regenerates half-way. The remainder must be healed by health packs or eating food.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to eat/drink or sleep to get your health back, there is no automatic regeneration

Answer (score 3):

You can only regenerate 50% of your health; the remainder must be healed with eating food, drinking sodas, or picking up health packs.

Source: [GTA Wiki](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Health#Trivia)